# Lables get overlapped and aligned to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the latest version of Bootstrap to create a search box. The search has a dropdown before the search button.

Clicking on the dropdown brings up a bunch of controls.

Here's the mark up for it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for snippets" />
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="filter">Filter by</label>
                                    <select class="form-control">
                                        <option value="0" selected>All Snippets</option>
                                        <option value="1">Featured</option>
                                        <option value="2">Most popular</option>
                                        <option value="3">Top rated</option>
                                        <option value="4">Most commented</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="contain">Author</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="contain">Contains the words</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    /* Search Box */
.dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 6px 20px;
}
.input-group-btn .btn-group {
    display: flex !important;
}
.btn-group .btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
.btn-group .btn:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-group .form-horizontal .btn[type="submit"] {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.form-horizontal .form-group {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.form-group .form-control:last-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #adv-search {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .dropdown.dropdown-lg {
        position: static !important;
    }
    .dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
        min-width: 500px;
    }
}
```

The issue is that label controls like 'Author' are getting aligned to the right as seen here:

[image: controls overlapping]

The Author label should come under the dropdown. What am I doing wrong?

P.S: Ignore the text in red as that a control under the searchbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label tags display as inline elements by default. That is, they want to stay on the same line as the content around them. To change that add display:block to the labels you want to force a new line. OR wrap them in their own personal div tag.

I added

```
label{
   display:block;
}
```

to your css to demonstrate.

https://jsfiddle.net/bLfv9dh6/

NOTE: THere is more CSS things going on for you though. I think there may be some ' float:left ' values being used somewhere. Those can mess you up if they are not cleared with the css property clear.

label{ clear:both; }
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

(PS veterans, don't spam me about w3schools. No its not perfect. But It's handy for beginners).

Comment: Many many thanks. This worked. The only issue remains now is with the blue search button at the bottom. What css can I use to fix that and bring it below the last text box.

Comment: add the same thing to a css rule for button{ }. To be specific, you can add it by the buttons class .btn-primary{ } or you can use button[type='submit'] to only affect submit buttons. Hopefully that works with the rest of your CSS.